# SFTP user upload to var/www/

Tags: server, permissions, 22.04, nginx, sftp

I created an SFTP user (upload) an added him to www-data. As well I set up the permissions for the var/www/html folder and edited the sshd_config like that:

```
Subsystem sftp  internal-sftp -l INFO 
Match User upload
            ChrootDirectory /var/www/html/i
            ForceCommand internal-sftp
            X11Forwarding no
            AllowTcpForwarding no
            PasswordAuthentication yes
```

history:

```
  186  sudo adduser upload
  187  sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
  188  sudo systemctl restart sshd
  189  sudo usermod -a -G www-data upload
  190  sudo ls -ld /var/
  191  sudo chmod 755 /var/
  192  sudo chown root:root /var/
  193  sudo chmod 755 /var/www/
  194  sudo chown root:root /var/www/
  195  sudo chmod 755 /var/www/html/
  196  sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html*
  197  sudo find /var/www/html/ -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
  198  sudo find /var/www/html -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \;
```

But Iam not able to connect to the Server. If I add the SFTP User without setting folder permission Iam able to connect but cant upload files and folders.

log from auth.log:

```
New session 134 of user upload.
sshd[11476]: fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory component "/var/www/html/"
pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user upload
```

I use ubuntu server 22.04 with nginx!

Comment: Is the `i` at the end of `ChrootDirectory /var/www/html/i` intended?

Comment: Yes it is. That the folder where I want to Upload files.

Comment: `But Iam not able to connect to the Server.` Do you get an error message on this?
And when you login `upload` via ssh (not sftp), can you access `/var/www/html/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by simply changing the sshd_config.

From

```
Match User upload
            ChrootDirectory /var/www/html/i
```

to

```
Match User upload
            ChrootDirectory /var/www/html
```